# Geopy reverse returns keyerrors for 'city', 'district' and 'borough' despite being in JSON response object

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror, geopy

I'm trying to run a very simple geopy reverse script that takes a lat-long coordinate and returns specifically the country, state and city. All three of these are easily pulled from the JSON response object. However, when I try to extract the 'city' feature, I get a KeyError. If I double check to see if 'city' is in the response object, it definitely is (see below), so what exactly is going on? I can extract country and state without issue, why not the city? I've also noticed this happening for district and borough.

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='latlongconvert')
df['address'] = df['LastMatchingLatLong'].apply(geolocator.reverse)

df['country'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x: (x.raw['address']['country']))
df['state'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x: (x.raw['address']['state']))
df['city'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x: (x.raw['address']['city']))
```

Where the last line creates the following error: `KeyError: 'city'`

When I look at a particular row it clearly contains the city key:

```
df['address'][0].raw['address']

Ouput:
{'tourism': 'Schwanentempel',
 'road': 'Auedamm',
 'suburb': 'Südstadt',
 'city': 'Kassel',
 'municipality': 'Niestetal',
 'state': 'Hessen',
 'postcode': '34121',
 'country': 'Deutschland',
 'country_code': 'de'}
```

I can even use `df['address'][0].raw['address']['city']` to extract it for that particular row.

Comment: Is city missing for some of the output?  That would yield a KeyError?

Comment: Ah it's always something simple - I'd assumed city was returned for every row instead of checking that directly. Thanks Paul, I'll try to be less of an idiot in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue, Geopy does not always return city, borough, district, etc. so using a lambda function without accounting for missing values will give you a keyerror.

The following code sorted this issue out for me:

```
df['country'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x: (x.raw['address']['country']))
df['state'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x: (x.raw['address']['state']))
df['city'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x: (x.raw['address']['city'] if 'city' in x.raw['address'].keys() else None ))
```